# How to manage dependencies for project support tooling like code generators?

Tags: java, maven

Never found a really satisfactory solution to this. How do you do it? I am looking for inspiration for new approaches.

For context, assume I write a generator that takes a project resource and generates a code file. But it could be any other project support tool - validator, converter, deployer etc. Often manually triggered actions that are not running as part of normal build.

Such tools typically require a few dependencies that are not required by the project itself at runtime.

Strategies that I have applied or considered in the past:

- add tool dependency to project anyway, and either mark it "provided" or filter it out during the packaging process (this is what I usually do, but now I am in danger of adding normal project code that uses the tool dependency, potentially resulting in an error that only manifests during runtime)
- use a script (trying hard to avoid scripts and their hidden dependencies and complexities)
- create separate support projects (trying hard to avoid project explosion, especially for seemingly small tasks that are handled by a few lines of code)
- subprojects / modules (only vaguely aware of this option, never really tried it)
- maven plugin that is run with a profile with separate dependencies (trying to avoid the separate project required to maintain the custom plugin)

Inspiration from answers and comments

- separate tools project shared by multiple projects

Comment: Why not build a "tools" project that contains all the support tools (or depending on what they do several such projects) which contain all the needed dependencies? If the tools are used internally and often in conjunction (on the same real project) then I'd not mind having them in one big package.

Comment: A valid approach for sure, thanks. Personally I would be reluctant to pull very project specific stuff away and mix it with specific stuff from many other unrelated projects.

Answer (score 0):

I just realized that maven and eclipse already solved exactly this problem for a very specific "tool": test code.

Test code often needs additional dependencies not used by the application itself.

People obviously invested quite a bit to keep the "test / tool" infrastructure within the same project, as opposed to creating a separate test-project:

- separate source locations (src/main/java, src/test/java)
- separate resource locations (src/main/resources, src/test/resources)
- a full-blown separate maven dependency scope "test", complete with transitive resolution
- separate compilation phases (compile / test) with separate dependency trees
- eclipse supports special junit launch configurations that are able to correctly resolve the test dependencies
- probably more stuff that I am not aware of currently

So, I am strongly considering to program all my supporting tools as "junit test cases".

I am planning to create and commit shared junit launch configs for the team that execute just one specific "test case", which will run the tool logic instead of testing.

The problem I have to solve is to avoid running these dummy tests during the normal maven test phase.

Also, writing this, I realize that there is even another such system already in place: the maven plugin infrastructure, that also has a separate dependency resolution mechanism. Although, so far it seems necessary or normal to create separate projects to create plugins. I will look into ways of writing and building project specific maven plugins without needing to create separate projects. I am thinking about generating the pom.xml needed for plugin compilation on the fly, and including all the test dependencies.